# Should this question be left open?

Tags: discussion

The question and it's associated answer:

[How can I find a compact camera with an ultra-wide lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38380/how-can-i-find-a-compact-camera-with-an-ultra-wide-lens)

This was recently opened and answered by a very prominent and respected member of this community. It asks what I see as a very valid general question about finding a specific camera model. The answer addresses this by directing the user to specific resources on an external website, and also gives a bit of context to help in using that website.

This is where I think the crux comes in. The *answer* reads very much like an advertisement for a specific website. That specific website is run by another very prominent and respected member of this community.

This question may come off as derogatory, but I am really at a loss as to why the answer needs to read so much like an advertisement.

Comment: I'm totally unrelated to the other website.  I just like it. I don't even know @Itai except through here. I recommend this web site too, for what _it_ is good for. I'm not sure of a way to make the recommendation read less "like an advertisement" and still be short and helpful, which I wanted this to be, because the goal is to have a landing target for the not-infrequent requests we get for such a camera.

Comment: This specifically is what I think makes it sound like an advertisement "Yes! The Neocamera camera database, regularly updated with new models, has a convenient search which will show just this.". The only thing missing from the advertisement is saying, "get it now, supplies are limited, only $19.95!". I also think that dismissing the competition as "unwieldy" is a great marketing tactic, as no one really knows what unwieldy is or why you find it that way.

Comment: Okay, I can expand on unwieldy, and I can soften the opening. Honestly, I think you're a bit testy because I wrote this in response to your question asking for an ultra-wide compact camera.

Comment: If you did those to things I would be much more forgiving. Opening any question with "YES!" is a bad idea in my mind if you want to come off as objective. Yes, my question sucked, and no I'm not testy because you taught me something! I only come here to learn as I'm well aware I don't know it all!

Comment: Hmm... Tricky. I kind of read it the same way too. It's a bit like a commercial that says "How do you get whites so white in your laundry?" answer: "You use the fantabulous Uberbright Laundry detergent to do it!" Having said that, it's also does help to answer a real question that comes up and Matt did disclose the connections. The information is useful, Itai's site is excellent, so some phrasing adjustments will help. Disclaimer: my better half is a professional writer in the advertising industry...

Comment: Okay, edited? That better? I'm not really testy either. Although I should go to sleep as I have a long day tomorrow. :)

Comment: Note, _disclosure_ alone does not keep it on topic. I know matt is not affiliated. Just a reference - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion

Comment: @mattdm - Better from my view. dpollitt - Agreed, but I think we can give some elbow room to strong participants when interpreting that. Within reason, of course, it does have to have value to the community.

Comment: Grr... system wouldn't let me do more than one 'at' reference. :p

Comment: Yes, I do think the edit makes it substantially better. I'm still wondering if we need a question on the site generalizing each spec and where it can be found, when we have this already: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-and-tools-for-comparing-cameras

Comment: Well, you know I'd like to close _every_ camera recommendation question as a duplicate of that one, but I don't think everyone agrees with me, so I see this as a sort of middle ground about a specific feature search. (And it happens that, for example, Snapsort might be a general recommendation but isn't good for this particular thing.)

Comment: Snapsort is a POS, whatever you do, just don't recommend _that_! Ok your middle ground may be a good idea. I see your theory now.

Comment: Well, a duplicate closure without delete keeps it around for search engines. Merges can also be used to tie them together. You know, we could be doing this better in chat...

Comment: Sorry, this does not add anything constructive, but, having done numerous google searches recently for camera review sites, I have noticed that Neocamera does not come up if I don't write the name myself in the search line, and even when I write it - Google thinks I made a spelling mistake and shows red underlining the word. So without a modest advertising a good site might go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster made some modifications to the original wording. All looks good now.